# How to add select all option to ion-select in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I tried adding ion-select-option and then tried to handle select all logic in the change event but change event doesn't fire at all. seems it doesn't support events

```
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Test</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValues" multiple="true">
            <ion-select-option (ionChange)="selectAll()">Select All</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option [value]="option" *ngFor="let option of  items">{{option}}
            </ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-10-start-template-hure6j?file=src/app/tabs/tabs.page.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Wesley that since ion-select is leveraging alert controller or popover under the hood the best way could be by using custom alert.
But if you have to keep "look and feel" of ion-select you could do the following:

HTML:

```
<ion-item (click)="openSelector(selector)">
      <ion-label>Pizza Toppings</ion-label>
      <ion-select #selector style="pointer-events: none" [interfaceOptions]="customAlertOptions" multiple="true" [value]="basket">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

TS:

```
import { Inject, Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  options = ["cheese", "pepperoni", "basil"];
  basket = [];

  listener;
  selectAllCheckBox: any;
  checkBoxes: HTMLCollection;

  customAlertOptions: any = {
    header: 'Pizza Toppings',
    subHeader: 'Select All:',
    message: '<ion-checkbox id="selectAllCheckBox"></ion-checkbox>'
  };

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  openSelector(selector) {
    selector.open().then((alert)=>{
      this.selectAllCheckBox = this.document.getElementById("selectAllCheckBox");
      this.checkBoxes = this.document.getElementsByClassName("alert-checkbox");
      this.listener = this.renderer.listen(this.selectAllCheckBox, 'click', () => {
          if (this.selectAllCheckBox.checked) {
            for (let checkbox of this.checkBoxes) {
              if (checkbox.getAttribute("aria-checked")==="false") {
                (checkbox as HTMLButtonElement).click();
              };
            };
          } else {
            for (let checkbox of this.checkBoxes) {
              if (checkbox.getAttribute("aria-checked")==="true") {
                (checkbox as HTMLButtonElement).click();
              };
            };
          }
      });
      alert.onWillDismiss().then(()=>{
        this.listener();
      });
    })
  }
  
}
```

Basically, you disable the default click handler on ion-select and pass 'selector' reference via ion-item bound click event. Then you use 'open' method of the ion-select to gain access to instance of 'alert'.
Since 'message' property of the alert options supports "sanitized" HTML you can still pass an HTML element to it (checkbox) with its ID. Then using document reference you get the checkbox and add listener (later to be removed on willDismiss hook).
Inside the click method you can implement the functionality of select all / none.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-2jqnsv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, It solved my issue, But I want to uncheck selectALL when any of item is unchecked. Any hint for it

Answer (score 3):

With Ionic multiple choice selects, there's no built in way to "select all" or "select none", but I came up with a custom solution that does just that. You're going to need to use a custom [alert component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert) instead of an `<ion-select>`, and you'll need to trigger the alert programatically.

```js
constructor(
    private alertController: AlertController,
    public platform: Platform
  ) {}

  async showAlert() {

    let buttons = [
      {
        text: 'All',
        cssClass: 'all-none-button',
        handler: () => {

          // check all checkboxes
          alert.inputs = alert.inputs.map((checkbox) => {
            checkbox.checked = true;
            return checkbox;
          });

          return false;
        }
      }, {
        text: 'None',
        cssClass: 'all-none-button',
        handler: () => {

          // uncheck all checkboxes
          alert.inputs = alert.inputs.map((checkbox) => {
            checkbox.checked = false;
            return checkbox;
          });

          return false;
        }
      }, {
        text: 'OK',
        handler: (data) => {
          // handle the data returned from the alert here
          console.log(data);
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
      }
    ];

    // adjust button order in four button layout for ios
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      const okButton = { ...buttons[2] };
      const cancelButton = { ...buttons[3] };
      buttons = [buttons[0], buttons[1], cancelButton, okButton];
    }

    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Select Option',
      inputs: [
        {
          label: 'Option 1',
          type: 'checkbox',
          value: 'one',
          checked: false
        },
        {
          label: 'Option 2',
          type: 'checkbox',
          value: 'two',
          checked: false
        },
        {
          label: 'Option 3',
          type: 'checkbox',
          value: 'three',
          checked: false
        },
      ],
      cssClass: 'four-button-alert',
      buttons: [...buttons]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

And you'll also need a little custom CSS to get the four button layout for this custom alert.

```css
.four-button-alert.md {
    .alert-button-group-vertical {
        display: block;

        button:nth-of-type(1),
        button:nth-of-type(2) {
            float: left;
            color: var(--ion-color-medium);
        }

        button:nth-of-type(3),
        button:nth-of-type(4) {
            float: right;
        }
    }
}

.four-button-alert.ios {
    .alert-button-group-vertical {
        flex-direction: row !important;

        button:nth-of-type(1) {
            color: var(--ion-color-medium);
        }

        button:nth-of-type(2) {
            color: var(--ion-color-medium);
            border-right: none;
        }
    }
}
```

The finished product looks like this (iOS & Android).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update July-2021 :** Added Search and moved select all & search to custom elements for easy management

**Code Sample :**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-10-start-template-6m73vb
[image]

**Previous Approach:**

I ended up using @Sergey Rudenko solution and created directive with some more improvements and handling select all in more scenarios. If any one interested please find the related code below

Solution 1 : Select All Checkbox directive. Based on @Sergey Rudenko answer

```
import { ContentChild, Directive, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSelect } from '@ionic/angular';
@Directive({
    selector: '[selectAllDirective]'
})
export class SelectAllDirective {
    @ContentChild(IonSelect) ionSelect;
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.ionSelect.el.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    }
    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick() {
        this.ionSelect.open().then(alert => {
            let id = "selectAllCheckBox";
            alert.message = `<ion-checkbox id="${id}"></ion-checkbox><ion-label class="m-l-15">Select All</ion-label>`;

            setTimeout(() => {
                let selectAll: any = alert.querySelector("#" + id);
                let checkboxes = Array.from(alert.querySelectorAll(".alert-checkbox"));
                let setState = () => {
                    let isAllChecked = checkboxes.every((c: any) => c.ariaChecked === "true");
                    let isAllUnChecked = checkboxes.every((c: any) => c.ariaChecked === "false");
                    if (isAllChecked || isAllUnChecked) {
                        selectAll.indeterminate = false;
                        selectAll.checked = isAllChecked;
                    } else {
                        selectAll.indeterminate = true;
                    }
                }
                setState();

                let checkboxListeners = checkboxes.map(ci => this.renderer.listen(ci, 'click', () => {
                    setTimeout(setState);
                }));

                let selectAllListener = this.renderer.listen(selectAll, 'click', (event) => {
                    setTimeout(() => alert.inputs = alert.inputs.map(i => { i.checked = event.target.checked; return i; }));
                });
                alert.onWillDismiss().then(() => {
                    selectAllListener();
                    checkboxListeners.forEach(i => i());
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Solution 2 : Select All with buttons using directive. Based on @Wesley answer

```
import { ContentChild, Directive, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSelect } from '@ionic/angular';
@Directive({
    selector: '[selectAllWithButtonDirective]'
})
export class SelectAllWithButtonDirective {
    @ContentChild(IonSelect) ionSelect;
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.ionSelect.el.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    }
    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick() {
        this.ionSelect.open().then(alert => {
            alert.cssClass = 'unset-vertical-buttons';
            alert.buttons = [{
                text: 'All',
                handler: () => {
                    alert.inputs = alert.inputs.map((checkbox) => {
                        checkbox.checked = true;
                        return checkbox;
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }, {
                text: 'None',
                handler: () => {
                    alert.inputs = alert.inputs.map((checkbox) => {
                        checkbox.checked = false;
                        return checkbox;
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }, ...alert.buttons,];
        });
    }
}
```

styles.css

```
.unset-vertical-buttons .alert-button-group-vertical {
    flex-direction: row !important;
}
.m-l-15 {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

both directives code sample :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-10-start-template-hu3y3u?file=src/app/tabs/select-all-with-button-directive.ts